# Get result of php with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button to call a php file with jQuery in my html file,

```
<script>    
$('#mysubmit').bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();
var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': 'http://localhost/lt/resources/lists/update.php',
                 'dataType': 'json'
               });
</script>
<input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
```

It works but I don't know how to get the result of the php file, i.e. the php file works, make an API POST and get the result as success or error, but  I don't know how to get through jQuery if the php file response is success or error.

Please help me I am a noob in Ajax and Jquery.

Comment: Inside PHP combine your response in one array (say `$response_array`), than output [json headers](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/php-headers-serve-json) and after that `json_encode($response_array)`. You can find [an example here](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/)

Answer (score 2):

your php file must respond with an echo:

```
<?php echo "success"; ?>
```

in your request do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://localhost/lt/resources/lists/update.php',
        'dataType': 'json'
        }).done(function(response){ /*DO SOMETHING WITH response*/ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a success \ error handler to see the response:

```
var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/lt/resources/lists/update.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                }
});
```

You should however follow @skobaljic's suggestion, and use a recognized response format such as JSON or XML - to make it easier to parse and more professional.

Using PHP it would look something like this:

```
<?php

   $result = ..... whatever you like to return here ...
   header('Content-Type: application/json');       
   echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery ajax success property.

```
    <script>    
     $('#mysubmit').bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();
         var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': 'http://localhost/lt/resources/lists/update.php',
             'dataType': 'json',
             'success' : function(returnData){
               alert(returnData); // or
               console.log(returnData);
             }
           });
   </script>
   <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Submit" />
```

what every you print at PHP side it will return in "success" function